# When python write PyCodeObject into a pyc file，In which case it will write a type of 'dict' data into pyc file?

Tags: python

```
#define TYPE_NULL               '0'
#define TYPE_NONE               'N'
#define TYPE_FALSE              'F'
#define TYPE_TRUE               'T'
#define TYPE_STOPITER           'S'
#define TYPE_ELLIPSIS           '.'
#define TYPE_INT                'i'
#define TYPE_INT64              'I'
#define TYPE_FLOAT              'f'
#define TYPE_BINARY_FLOAT       'g'
#define TYPE_COMPLEX            'x'
#define TYPE_BINARY_COMPLEX     'y'
#define TYPE_LONG               'l'
#define TYPE_STRING             's'
#define TYPE_INTERNED           't'
#define TYPE_STRINGREF          'R'
#define TYPE_TUPLE              '('
#define TYPE_LIST               '['
#define TYPE_DICT               '{'
#define TYPE_CODE               'c'
#define TYPE_UNICODE            'u'
#define TYPE_UNKNOWN            '?'
#define TYPE_SET                '<'
#define TYPE_FROZENSET          '>'
```

I know python mainly write number and string datas into pyc.
Because PyCodeObject include attributes such as co_consts and so on, python will write list and tuple into the file.
However, I want to know that in which case,python will write TYPE_DICT data into a pyc file?

Answer (score 0):

I would expect it to be whenever there is some code in an external module that defines an initialised dictionary, i.e. one that is not empty to start with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.In fact,if you have a initialised dictionary which is not empty.Once it is compiled,no dictionary exists.

Comment: for example,code like this"c={1:'hello',2:{2:['hello']}}",it will be compiled into some numbers and strings,no dict data.